# Android User Taps My Notification and Return to my app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service, android-notifications

I am showing a `Notification` for a background `Service` using the `startForefround()` method.

```
  if (notif == null) {

        // Create the pending intent
        Intent intentForeground = new Intent(this, BackgroundLocationService.class)
        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);    
        PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intentForeground, 0);

        notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
         .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
         .setTicker(getText(R.string.location_service_starting))
         .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
         .setOngoing(true)
         .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
         .build();
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    }
    startForeground(notificationID, notif);
```

**It correctly shows the notification to the user and when I slide down the notification bar I would like to have the user tap the notification and return to my app. How can I do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.logo2, "app is running on the background!", System.currentTimeMillis());

notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "title", "message!", contentIntent);

this.startForeground(1023, notification);
```

Comment: Ah, I was missing the MainActivity.class part. Thanks!